# SharePoint List - Auto Increment based on count of another column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, microsoft-flow

I have managed to get an auto incrementing column.  See below.  So the Ref column is incrementing based on how many items there are already in 'Type'.  In effect there could be multiple number 1s, but they are unique based on having 'Type' appended to it.

I have the one dimensional increments working based on 'Id' and using O365 Flows in SharePoint.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Please following steps:**

1.Create new list named "**Auto Increment**" and add some columns in the list.

[image]

2.Click **Integrate** >> **Power Automate** >> **Create a flow**

[image]

3.Create the MS Flow

a.Add "**When an item is created**" trigger

b.Add "**Get item**" action

c.Add "**Get items**" action:

- **Filter Query**: **Types eq 'Types Value'**

d.Add "**Compose**" action:

- **Inputs**: **length(body('Get_items')?['value'])**

e.Add "**Condition**" action:

- **Ref is equal to null**

f.On the "**If yes**" branch, add "**Update item**" action:

- **Ref**: **R_Outputs_Types Value**

[image]

4.**Save** and **Test** this MS Flow

[image]

======================== **Updated Answer** ========================

**Please follwoing steps:**

1.Go to the specific list >> **List settings** >>  scroll to **Columns** sections >> click on the specific column

2.On the Edit Column page, check this column's dispalyname.

[image]

Comment: Seems very logical - thank you @EchoDu_MSFT.  I get an error on 'Get Items'. The error is that "Column 'Type' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."  The column is very much present on the list.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, RDW. Thanks for your reply. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!

Comment: Wow- excellent catch.  Thank you.  Flow now works, however it does not increment.  Every item has the same number, which is the latest one.  Any thoughts?  Thank you!!

Comment: Also I have noticed that in the final Step, I get the 'Type' Field, but cannot add Dynamic content, it only offers the drop down.  Maybe a clue to something I am missing.

Comment: Output is as per below.  I am guessing that it works, unless I add several at the same time?  As in, the workflow processes them all at once and therefore adds same reference?                                                                                                                            
Ref Type
R1_Car Car
R_1_Bus Bus
R_1_Bike Bike
R_1_Bus Bus
R_2_Bike Bike
R_2_Bus Bus
R_5_Bus Bus
R_5_Bus Bus
R_5_Bus Bus
R_4_Bike Bike
R_4_Bike Bike

Comment: Further info.  Seems like a refresh is required after each item is processed?  If I add a few line, but do not refresh after each, I end up with duplicate References.

Comment: After creating each new item you need to refresh page.Because every time Flow is triggered, it takes a certain amount of time to operate.

Comment: Thanks.   What if two people updated at once, rare chance I know.  Is there no way to trigger at the end of each row as it were?  Once a new item is saved, and then iteratively?   So I could then say add/copy in 100 new items from a spreadsheet and have each item processed individually?  Thus eliminating any chance of a duplicate is reduced where it would then process on a per line level?